# How to output results of loop

Tags: r

I'd like to output the results of this loop in an excel. Could someone please assist me with this?

```
i=1
j=1
k=1

for (i in 1:length(CAT_LIST)){
  data_1 <- subset(Collated_dump, Category.Name == CAT_LIST[i])
  SUPP_LIST<-unique(data_1$Supplier.Description)
  
  for (j in 1:length(SUPP_LIST)){
    data_2 <- subset(data_1, Supplier.Description == SUPP_LIST[j])
    SUBCAT_LIST<-unique(data_2$Sub_Category_Name)
    for (k in 1:length(SUBCAT_LIST)){
      COGS <- sum(data_2[data_2$Sub_Category_Name == SUBCAT_LIST[k],"REAL.COGS"])
    }
  }
}
```

Expecting an output with Category name, Supplier name & the sum of COGS.

Comment: First, store the results of your loop into a structure of some kind - a list or data frame or whatever is appropriate for the data.  Afterwards, write the data to excel - there are a few packages like `xlsx` you can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following (not sure if I fully understood what you are trying to do):

```
library(writexl)

CAT_LIST <- c("Category1", "Category2", "Category3")  
Collated_dump <- data.frame(...)  # Replace with your data

result_df <- data.frame(Category = character(),
                         Supplier = character(),
                         Sub_Category = character(),
                         Total_COGS = numeric(),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through categories
for (i in 1:length(CAT_LIST)){
  data_1 <- subset(Collated_dump, Category.Name == CAT_LIST[i])
  SUPP_LIST <- unique(data_1$Supplier.Description)
  
  # Loop through suppliers within each category
  for (j in 1:length(SUPP_LIST)){
    data_2 <- subset(data_1, Supplier.Description == SUPP_LIST[j])
    SUBCAT_LIST <- unique(data_2$Sub_Category_Name)
    
    # Loop through sub-categories within each supplier
    for (k in 1:length(SUBCAT_LIST)){
      COGS <- sum(data_2[data_2$Sub_Category_Name == SUBCAT_LIST[k], "REAL.COGS"])
      
      result_df <- rbind(result_df, data.frame(Category = CAT_LIST[i],
                                               Supplier = SUPP_LIST[j],
                                               Sub_Category = SUBCAT_LIST[k],
                                               Total_COGS = COGS))
    }
  }
}

write_xlsx(result_df, path = "output_results.xlsx")
```